# airflow TimeDeltaSensor fails with unsupported operand type

Tags: airflow

In my DAG I have a [`TimeDeltaSensor`](http://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/sensors/time_delta_sensor.html) created using:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.sensors import TimeDeltaSensor 
wait = TimeDeltaSensor(
    task_id='wait',
    delta=timedelta(seconds=300),
    dag=dag
)
```

However when it runs I get error

> - Subtask: [2018-07-13 09:00:39,663] {models.py:1427} ERROR - unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'

[image]

Airflow version is 1.8.1.

The code is basically lifted from [Example Pipeline definition](https://artwr.github.io/airflow-workshop-dataengconf-sf-2017/anatomy_of_a_dag.html#example-pipeline-definition) so I'm nonplussed as to what the problem could be. Any ideas?

Comment: What does that task show for the execution_date? Found by going to Task Instance Details page

Comment: @jamiet Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @SpandanSingh ah, unfortunately I don't remember, sorry. That said, the suggestion from tobi6 in his proposed answer looks plausible. Apologies for not coming back here to update the thread 7 months ago.

Comment: It looks like this is caused by the `TimeDeltaSensor` being dependent on the DAG having a schedule that is not `@once`. See [issue 9046 here|https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/9046]. 

I'm using airflow 1.10.6 and I had this issue. It may be resolved in later versions.

Answer (score 4):

Looking into the source code you linked there is one line that strikes me as interesting in this case:

```
target_dttm = dag.following_schedule(context['execution_date'])
```

Which means: If you don't have setup a proper DAG schedule this component will try to add its time delta to `None`.

I am not sure if the code in the question is just an example or the whole thing. My suggestion is: Add a DAG schedule with is other than `None`.