# Why the TimeSensor Operator give me this error

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

**airflow TimeDeltaSensor fails with unsupported operand type**

I'm use *Airflow* on **"Google Cloud Composer"**, and I need to get data from "FaceBook Ads" for different accounts, so I need put some delay seconds between two calls.
I've tried with *TimeDeltaSensor*, but the insert of the call of this operator, in the dag chain, send the code in error.

This is my dag:

```py
dag_start_date = get_yesterday(at_midnight=True)
dag_args = get_dag_args(FLOW, dag_name, dag_start_date=dag_start_date)
with DAG(dag_id=dag_name, default_args=dag_args, start_date=dag_start_date, schedule_interval='@once') as dag:
    worker = FacebookAdsToBigQuery(FLOW, dag)
    end_date = dag_start_date
    start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=3)
    worker.run_dag(start_date, end_date)
```

And this the peice of code about the TimeDeltaSensor:

```py
....
        for level in FacebookAdsToBigQuery.LEVELS:
            table_schema_fname = self.level_table_schema_file[level]
            schema_fields = bb_utils.load_json_file(table_schema_fname)
            for j, account_id in enumerate(self.account_ids):
                tsk_prefix = f"{self.dag.dag_id}_{account_id}_{level}"
                delta = j * 10
                if delta > 0:
                    wait_x_nextact_tsk = TimeDeltaSensor(task_id=f'{tsk_prefix}_wait_{delta}',
                                                         delta=timedelta(seconds=delta), dag=self.dag)
                else:
                    wait_x_nextact_tsk = DummyOperator(task_id=f'{tsk_prefix}_nowait', dag=self.dag)

....
```

This is the error:

> [2019-10-08 11:18:25,547] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 199692: Subtask facebook_ads_233070883986464_ad_wait_40 [2019-10-08 11:18:25,546] {cli.py:520} INFO - Running on host airflow-worker-5fd4678587-l6nlf
>
> [2019-10-08 11:18:25,642] {models.py:1796} ERROR - unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'

The cause can be that the operator don't can understand the dag parameter **schedule_interval='@once'**?

Thanks

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51346711/3679900) might be helpful

Comment: Hi @y2k-shubham, as I wrote i need that the dag ran '@once'
and in the link *tobi6* wrote that the problem was that the dag was scheduled at _None_. But the bug is really that the code not manage the *None* value